# Fluid generate URI of another extension in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I have a Typo3 Extbase plugin called "PluginOne".
And I have to call another Controller Action of the "PluginTwo" in "PluginOne".

How is it possible...

I tried this in PluginOne

```
<f:uri.action action='show' controller='Gallery' extensionName='PluginTwo' pluginName='PluginTwo' />
```

But it gnerate the wrong url, the generated url contains ID of the Current Plugin ie 'PluginOne'.

Comment: in extensionName, you wrote 'PluginTwo' instead of the extension's name

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```html
<f:uri.action action="list" controller="Inquirer" extensionName='PluginTwo' pluginName='PluginTwo' arguments="{uid: 1}"  pageUid="62" />
```

this one, 
it works for me